# decidability special case of column generation problem

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, computability-theory, lattices

I have the following problem:

Input: sub-spaces $V_1, \dots, V_d$ of $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$

Question: are there $v_i \in V_i$ such that the matrix $(v_1, \dots, v_d)$ has determinant $\pm 1$ (equivalently, is $v_1, \dots, v_d$ a basis of $\mathbb{Z}^d$)?

Is this problem known to be decidable?